# Statistical tests for two rates

Tags: statistical-significance, epidemiology

For a paper I am writing, I am comparing influenza burden in two locations. For each location, I have the rate of symptomatic influenza infections per 100,000 population, as well as a 95% confidence interval for these rates. What is a good statistical test for seeing if they are significantly different? Can I just look to see if the confidence intervals overlap? I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but these two locations used different surveillance methods/calculations to find these rates, but we can assume that both methods are pretty good.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How many people are in each location?

Comment: This is an A/B testing problem. You can use this calculator to do it for you: https://abtestguide.com/calc/